# Adding/removing from a set/list across threads

Tags: python, multithreading, list, variables, set

I am working on a project that has code similar to the following.  I am wondering if it is possible to make this thread safe?  I need to be able to keep track of which elements have been changed and exclude them from the next loop.  Note, the functions t1 and t2 are not performing the same functionality.

Put simply, I need to modify a list, set or something similar to be able to keep track of progress and know when to quit the loops in each thread.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading

elements = list()
elements.add({
    'key': 'old_value'
})

elements.add({
    'key': 'old_value2'
})

changed_elements = list()
def change(element, value):
    element['key'] = value
    changed_elements.append(element)
    elements.remove(element)

def t1:
    for i in range(0, 99):
        for element in elements:
            if condition:
                change(element, value)

def t2:
    for i in range(0, 49):
        for element in elements:
            if condition2:
                change(element, value2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=t1).start()
    Process(target=t2).start()
```

Comment: What you need is [Thread Synchronization](https://hackernoon.com/synchronization-primitives-in-python-564f89fee732).

Comment: @VasilisG. I saw that article in my googling, however, when I tried to implement it, it did not work...  Could you maybe provide an example of how I could implement those techniques with my use case?

Comment: Try some of the synchronization mechanisms and post your attempts here so that we can help. You also need to change `elements.add` to `elements.append` and place round brackets after `t1` and `t2`.